# Load a javascript file into a module pattern on Client-side

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I have a simple javascript module pattern that executes client-side.

```
var module = (function() {

    var _privateVariable = 10;

    function publicMethod () {

        console.log("public method; private variable: " + _privateVariable);

    }

    return {
        publicMethod: publicMethod
    };

})();
```

Let's say I want to load in another module (which also uses a module pattern) from a separate javascript file. How do I do that, i.e. something like:

```
?? Load other module here ??
var _other_module = ??

var module = (function() {

    var _privateVariable = 10;

    function publicMethod () {

        console.log("public method; private variable: " + _privateVariable);

        console.log("public method; other module: " + other_module.publicMethod());
    }

    return {
        publicMethod: publicMethod
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. To load another module form another file you need to use a Module formats.

It's a long story, i will try to shorten.

Let's talk first about the old way. earlier the developer used to load alle the JS-Files in a certain order in the HTML-Page. If we have 2 JS-Files index.js and variables.js and we want to get a variable from varible.js in index.js, we had load them like that

```
<script src="variables.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

But this is not a good way and has many negatives.

The right way is to use a Module formats.

There are many Module formats,

- Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD)
- CommonJS
- Universal Module Definition (UMD)
- System.register
- ES6 module format

and each format has own Syntax.

For example CommonJS:

```
var dep1 = require('./dep1');  

module.exports = function(){  
   // ...
}
```

but the Browsers dont't understand that. so we need a Module bundlers or Module loaders
to convert our code to code which browsers can understand.

**Module bundlers**: Bundle your inter-dependent Javascript files in the correct order

- Browserify
- Webpack

**Module loaders**: a module loader interprets and loads a module written in a certain module format.

- RequireJS
- SystemJS

This [article](https://www.jvandemo.com/a-10-minute-primer-to-javascript-modules-module-formats-module-loaders-and-module-bundlers/#) will help you so much to understand exactly how modules work.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure which context you are doing this.

But. In node.JS this would be typically done by

> `module1.js`

```
module.exports.publicMethod = function() {}
```

> `index.js`

```
const module1 = require('./module1.js');
module1.publicMethod();
```

or

```
const {publicMethod} = require('./module1.js');
publicMethod();
```

Comment: He said client side, didnt he ? :)

Comment: Fair enough @noa-dev. Although client-side could also be an Electron app with build in node.js. I didn't read Browser. And thnx for that -1